# Running multiple statements on DB2 z/OS (v12)

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I'm trying to run multiple statements at once. When I run each of the following 3 statements on its own, I get no issues. However, when I run all 3 at once, I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

My server is v12 and I am using DBeaver Community as the client with a JDBC connection.

[image: Screenshot of stuff]

Comment: This depends on how you execute these statements. If you run them with `Ctrl+Enter`, it tries to run all these statements as a single one, but such a "compound" statement is not supported by DB2 for Z/OS. If you want to run them as a script (a sequence of independent statements), you should use `ALT+X`.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!